# Equality between sines of different angles

Tags: trigonometry

I'm studying WKB approximation for quantum mechanics and somewhere in the demonstration I get this equality: $Asin(\theta_1)=Bsin(\theta_2)$, and then the text proceeds to show that $\theta_1 + \theta_2 = (n+1)\pi$ with $A=(-1)^nB$. Why is that?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: There are lots of sets of $A$, $B$, $\theta_{1}$ and $\theta_{2}$ values such that $A\sin(\theta_{1})=B\sin(\theta_{2})$ without your other condtions.  Clearly, there's some additional context here that is missing from your question.

Answer (score 0):

$$
A\sin x - B\sin y = ?
$$
we can use double angle formula
$$
\sin(x + y) = \sin x \cos y + \cos x \sin y = 0
$$
then we have $x+y = k\pi$ If this is the case then we can
$$
\begin{align}
\sin(x)\cos(x-k\pi) + \cos (x)sin(y)  &=& \sin(x)\cos(x)\cos(k\pi) + \cos(x)\sin(y)  \\
&=&\sin(x)\cos(x)(-1)^k + \cos(x)\sin(y)
\end{align}
$$
where $(-1)^k  = \cos(k\pi)$
to finish it off
$$
B= \cos(x)
$$
we then have
$$
\sin(x)B(-1)^k + B \sin(y) = 0
$$
or
$$
A\sin(x) + B\sin(y) = 0
$$
Play around with the formulation but this is the approach.

Comment: Actually from $A \sin(\theta_1)=B \sin(\theta_2)$ the OP wants to get $\theta_1 + \theta_2 = (n+1)\pi$ and $A=(-1)^nB$, which I don't think is true

Comment: @EugenCovaci If you want to get the second equation in my post you need the requirement $x+y$ be a multiple of $\pi$ I think the $n+1$ comes from the sign he wants  for the final output. I will check this page later and adjust accordingly. Thanks for your input :).